On what website can I find an audio recording of the Korean word 양치류?
I have searched for a youtube video titled, "How to pronounce 양치류".
At the time of my writing, I cannot find a pronunciation video on youtube.

Sometimes, wiktionary.org has NO audio recording for a particular word.
At the time of my writing, wiktionary has no audio file for how to pronounce  양치류.
"EE-AW-NG-CH-EE-OH" is a rough transliteration of 양치류.
However, I would prefer to have an audio and/or video recording rather than simply read a written transliteration.

What about using the papago website?
https://papago.naver.com/

You can type the korean word 양치류 in "Type the text to translate."
Then click the speaker button to listen to the pronunciation.

*I guess it's a TTS voice.
